# Can I change the background color of elevated button permanently in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have made a list from a  string and then made button from that list. Now, I want that when the button is pressed it will change it's color. Currently I have done the following but it only change the button color for a moment. Can it be permanently changed?

```
List<Widget> _buildButtonsWithNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.length; i++) {
      buttonsList.add(
        new ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => {
           
          },
          child: Text(wordlist[i]),
          style: ButtonStyle(
              overlayColor: getColor(Colors.white, Colors.teal),
              backgroundColor: getColor(Colors.blue, Colors.red)),
        ),
      );
    }
    return buttonsList;
  }

  MaterialStateProperty<Color> getColor(Color color, Color colorPressed) {
    final getColor = (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return colorPressed;
      } else {
        return color;
      }
    };
    return MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor);
  }
```

Comment: check my answer below if you want change color on button pressed

Comment: What do you mean by `permanently`?

Answer (score 1):

Use styleFrom. It will work in your case

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => {
       
      },
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(

                                   //Add your conditions for button color here

                                  ),
```

Comment: Do I need to do it inside onPress() function? If I do so then, each time I press the button another same type button appear.

Comment: No. Do it outside onpressed()

Comment: Set a bool variable to change on  onpressed().  Set conditions for color inside style: ElevatedButton.syleFrom() according to this bool variable

Comment: problem is whenever I add something in setstate method new button is keep showing up for each click.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you, refer official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) for `ElevatedButton()`

Declare one boolean varible,you used Stateful widget

```
bool isPressed = true;
```

your button widget:

```
  SizedBox(
      width: 150,
      height: 50,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(
            () {
              isPressed = !isPressed;
            },
          );
        },
        child: Text( 'OK'),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: isPressed ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen before button Pressed ->  [image]

Your result screen after button Pressed -> [image]

Comment: I did the same thing problem is whenever I put something in the setState function, new button appear when button is pressed

Comment: what di you exact want?

Comment: I just want when the button is pressed just the button color will be changed. But when I press button a new set of button appear(with changed color) with the previous.

Comment: Ok you don't need change the text of button only change color? then check my updated answer